# I think I have the xpaths right but keep getting "Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)"

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape Yelp with Scrapy and everything seems to be just fine. I even made sure that the url and all xpaths work in Scrapy shell properly but I keep getting: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), and does not give an error I can fix.

I also tried looking for similar problems but nothing seems to be related to what's happening to my spider.

```
from scrapy import Spider
from ..items import YelpItem
import scrapy
import re 

class YelpSpider(Spider):
    name = "yelp"
    allowed_domains = ['www.yelp.com']
    # Defining the list of pages to scrape
    start_url = ['https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Dog&find_loc=Boston%2C%20MA&start=0' + str(1 * i)  for i in range(0, 3)]

def parse(self, response):
    # Defining rows to be scraped
    rows = response.xpath('//[@id="wrap"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/ul/li').extract_first()
    for row in rows:
        # Scraping Busines' Name
        name = row.xpath('.//p/a/text()').extract_first()

        # Scraping Phone number
        phone = rows.xpath('.//div[1]/p[1][@class= "lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2pB8f textcolor--normal__373c0__K_MKN text-align--right__373c0__3ARv7"]/text()').extract_first()

        # scraping area
        area = rows.xpath('.//p/span[@class = "lemon--span__373c0__3997G"]/text()').extract_first()


        item = YelpItem()    
        item['name'] = name
        item['phone'] = phone
        item['area'] = area

        yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `start_url` to `start_urls`.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how simple this was, thank you so much